# pipe error : Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'concat',
  pure: true,
})
export class ConcatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value: string, args: string[]): string {
    return value?.concat(...args);
  }
}
```

When I try to concating in ngFor:

```
 <mat-option *ngFor="let name of names$ | async; index as i" [value]="i" [id]="'firstName' | concat: [i]">
```

I have this pipe where I concat things in the template side, but i get this error:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

How can I fix or extend my pipe?

Comment: Does that error show up for this code or code that calls this? If it is on the calling code, you should show how you do that.

Comment: Yes,sorry I edited my answer

Comment: you could simply do `[id]="'firstName' + i"`, without pipe for such a simple thing ;)

Comment: Yes, but I want to extend the pipe, and I try to think how can I do it, but I stucked,But the reason I want to extend is the performance, it's faster

Answer (score 1):

It means you receive numbers, not strings. You should first try to log what happens in `value` and `args`. Then you would have to cast numbers into string:

```
let strValue: string;
if (typeof value === 'number') {
  strValue = parseInt(value);
} else {
  strValue = value;
}
```

same goes for the args array:

```
argsStrs: string[] = args.map(arg => {
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    return parseInt(arg);
  } else {
    return arg;
  }
}
```